# Create a symbolic copy of another directory that has it's own local data

Tags: linux, symlink, ln

I have a directory `foo` that contains files and directories. I want to create a new directory `foo_0311` that contains the same files as `foo` (and sees updates when the files change), but that allows by to perform `touch foo_0311/a.txt` and not have `a.txt` appear in `foo`.

I used to have a way of doing this, but lost it when my bash history disappeared, and I haven't been able to reconstruct it. I remember it involved first creating `foo_0311` and then using `ln` like the following:

```
mkdir foo_0311
ln ???
```

but I can't remember the options for it. IIRC, when I `cd` to the directory after performing this operation and issue `ls -l`, the files did not appear as links, but changes were reflected in the original `foo` directory, while new files I created in `foo_0311` were absent in `foo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask `cp` to create a so-called link tree for you:

```
cp -al foo foo_0311
```

`-a` copies everything recursively, and `-l` creates hard links for files instead of copying them.

If `foo_0311` already exists then you should use

```
cp -al foo/* foo_0311
```

instead.

This creates hard links rather than symbolic links, so they don't appear with `->` in the output of `ls -l` (but you can spot them because of the `2` in the second column). Any new files you create in either directory won't appear in the other, but files you edit in one will appear in the other, *as long as* they're actually modified in place. (Editors like Emacs create new files and move them into place, which breaks this, although it's actually very useful with link trees because it allows a form of copy-on-write...)

Comment: This seems to create a directory `foo` inside `foo_0311`. Is there a way to avoid that? I was also seeing that with some of the solutions using `ln` that I tried.

Comment: If `foo_0311` exists, then `cp` as given copies `foo` inside `foo_0311`; you need to delete `foo_0311` first.

Comment: It seems that `cp -al foo/* foo_0311` may work. I still need to complete verification. I'm still puzzled why `ln -s foo/* foo_0311` and `ln -P foo/* foo_0311` both don't work (using `-s` leads to errors when I try to copy files after `cd`-ing to `foo_0311`; `-P` leads to `hard link not allowed for directory`).

Comment: Yes, that form of `cp` is equivalent, it only requires that `foo_0311` already exist. With `ln`, try `cd foo_0311; ln ../foo/* .`; as long as `foo` doesn't contain any directories it should give you what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see -- You are trying to make some directory and then create a symbolic link to that directory ...... Just like how windows machines have the main program inside “Program Files”  and an icon(aka...symbolic link in *nix world). To achive this you will need to simply do :

```
=>> mkdir  -p ~/home/folder/        "will make the directory for you if it doesn't exist"

=>> touch     ~/home/folder/file.txt  "will create the file"
```

> and now create a symbolic link for that file ,

```
ln -sf ~/home/folder/file.txt      ~/home/folder2/file.txt
```

You may want to run it with sudo, depending on where you creating the symlink. you can also check the man page of ln [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ln)....and you are done.